# Funçao match jQuery, como obter os matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu posso obter os matches usando a funçao match?

```
console.log($("COMMANDO database -> run []").match(/COMMAND\S*(.*)\S*->\S*(.*)/g)[0]);
```

Em teoria eu teria de obter `database`, `run` e o que esta dentro do `[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O método [Match](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) não é do JQuery, é nativo da linguagem Javascript, modifiquei sua expressão regular para pegar o contéudo dentro dos colchetes.

```js
var regex = /\S*(.*)\S*->\S*(.*)\[(.*?)\]/i; 
var input = "COMMANDO database -> run [conteúdo]"; 
if(regex.test(input)) {
  var matches = input.match(regex);
  for(i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
        alert(matches[i]);
    }
} else {
  alert("Nenhuma combinação encontrada.");
}
```

Comment: +1 para testar com `.test` antes! Eu sempre fazia o `.match` e verificava se o resultado não era `null`! Assim é bem mais elegante!

Comment: Para deixar a resposta mais completa eu apenas incluiria o [link para a documentação de `.match` na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 1):

Não existe função `match` no biblioteca jQuery. Talvez queira usar a função `String.match` nativa do javascript. Ela funciona assim:

```
"COMMANDO database -> run []".match(/COMMAND\S*(.*)\S*->\S*(.*)/)
```

Repare que foi preciso remover a flag `g` da regex para capturar grupos. Note também que a string contém `COMMANDO` enquanto que a regex procura `COMMAND`. Nesse caso, não há match.